# Disable the output of matplotlib pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array `A` of shape (1000, 2000). I use matplotlib.pyplot to plot the array, which means 1000 curves, using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(A)
```

The figure is fine but there are a thousand lines of:

```
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xXXXXXXXX>
```

Can I disable this output?

Answer (score 66):

You can also suppress the output by use of `;` at the end (assuming you are doing this in some sort of interactive environment)

```
 plot(A);
```

Answer (score 63):

[`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#:%7E:text=Returns%3A,Line2D) returns a list of [`Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) objects. To suppress this output, assign the return object a name:

```
_ = plt.plot(A)
```

`_` is often used to indicate a temporary object which is not going to be used later on. Note that this output you are seeing will only appear in the interpreter, and not when you run the script from outside the interpreter.

Other [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) methods return objects, which may be printed, can also be suppressed by assigning them with `_ = ...`.

Answer (score 29):

`plt.show()`

This way there is no need to create unnecessary variables.

E.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(A)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

use a semi-colon after the plot command

eg:
plt.imshow(image,cmap);

will display the graph and stop the verbose

Comment: Given the code in the [Rev1 OP](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12056115/1), `plt(A)`, which was a typo for `plot(A)`, this answer is a duplicate of this [Rev1 Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12059056/1), `plot(A);`, which already shows to add `;` to the end. This answer adds nothing new.

Answer (score -1):

## To ignore warnings

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: This does not work.  The inline will still output.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. `<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xXXXXXXXX>` is an object **Returned** by `plt.plot`, it is not a warning, and this will do nothing for the issue.